# How to worship a holy river?

Tags: rituals, rivers

When a river gets [pushkaram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushkaram), I see many people leaving deepam at holy rivers.

- What are the known ways to worship a river?
- Why do they do it?

> [image: Women worshipping a river]

Comment: The best you can do is to keep it clean always!!!